# truncated google search api result url

Tags: python, google-api

I have the following code that I use to in order to search google,

```
def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res

result = google_search("testtest", my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
for item in result['items']:
        print item['formattedUrl']
```

The problem I have is that `item['formattedUrl']` sometimes gets truncated and return `...` in the url. for example instead of `http://www.example.com/page/1` the result can be `http://www.example.com/.../1` how can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `http://www.example.com/.../1` how the actual url is on the page source? Most browsers will display the truncated url bottom of the window for display purposes. If you hover long enough, it'll show the full url

Comment: Its not browser related, the google api returns the url like this.